# How to upload icon to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an icon to Firebase Storage. When I try to upload IconData, I get error that icon data is not file. How can I solve this problem?

```
final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage()
        .ref()
        .child(categoryRef.document().documentID + '.jpg');

    final StorageUploadTask task = storageReference.putFile(icon);
```

Comment: Icons in Flutter are characters in fonts - you could upload the whole font, but I assume that this is not what you want to do.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Do you know any icon picker for flutter?

Comment: Can you add what type is `icon`? As it says it has to be a `File`

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I am looking for smth like icon picker for category. For example for work category user can select icon which is  Icons.work from picker

Answer (score 1):

The code for uploading an **image file** to your firebase storage in flutter is as below,

```
Future<String> uploadImage(File image) async {
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =   FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Images/${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;

    String storagePath = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    Uri finalPath = Uri.parse(storagePath);

    return storagePath;
  }
```

This will surely upload your file to firebase storage and at last will return you the **URL path** of the stored file.

Answer (score 0):

you can download custom icons from [flaticon.com](http://flaticon.com) or [icons8.com](http://icons8.com) and the upload them to your storage and associate them with categories.Assuming you are using a drop down to load categories ,you could use a `ListTile()` and show your icons in  `leading:`
.Not a good approach for users with a poor connectivity .